# Asymptotic expansion of an integral, related to Maass forms

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, cv.complex-variables, automorphic-forms, asymptotics, maass-forms

I am trying to compute the asymptotic expansion of the integral
$I(t) = \int_{C} e^{\sqrt{1+u}(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{u}})}\frac{u^\eta}{\sqrt{1+u}}du$
as $t$ is real and $t\rightarrow +\infty$, where $\eta$ a fixed complex number, and $C$ is a unit circle. It occurs in the theory of Maass forms/Automorphic forms.
I understand the Laplace method to compute the asymptotic expansion for the integral from 0 to 
$\infty$ but here is in the unit circle and at the point $-1$ the denominator $\sqrt{1+u}=0$.
Do you have any suggestion to compute it?
Thank you very much.

Comment: denote $\sqrt{1+u}=v$

Comment: @Fedor: Can you explain more? I tried but got nothing. Thank you.

Comment: The substitution suggested by Fedor Petrov is standard to get rid of the denominator. After that substitution I neglected the $1/t$ in the exponent for lowest order and did some high accuracy Mathematica numerical calculation. The results suggest that $I(t) = A e^{t^2}/t$ for large $t$ (between 2 and 50), $A$ some constant. However, I did not (yet) succeed in getting that result with a steepest descent approximation. Whatever critical points I try, I get some prefactor of $t^2$ other than 1 in the exponent.